# Interface function C#

Tags: c#, function, interface

I have a function which implement an interface. something like this:

```
string IMyInterface.MyFunction()
{
   do something;
}
```

This function is available outside of my class. All working perfect.
Now I also need to call this function from another LOCAL non public function. like this:

```
void Func2()
{
  string s;
  s = MyFunction();
}
```

The problem is I get this error:
"the name MyFunction does not exist in the current context local"

Any help will be appreciated.

TY.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've implemented the interface method explicitly.
Cast "this" to the interface, and you're there:

```
void Func2()
{
    string s = ((IMyInterface)this).MyFunction();  
}
```

Comment: Or implement the function implicitly.

Answer (score 4):

It is [explicitly implemented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157%28VS.80%29.aspx). You can only call it from a reference of the type `IMyInterface`. To call it internally, you need to cast `this`.

```
s = ((IMyInterface)this).MyFunction();
```

Consider to implement it implicitly, explicit implementations are tricky, you need a good reason to use it.

Comment: I saw your comment after I deleted my redundant answer. (For the record, I agree.)

Comment: Explicit implementation is one of the beauties of C#, if you ask me. I really miss that sometimes. Casting to interface can be a really clear way to write self-explaining code. Off course depending on what your interfaces are and so on.

Comment: @Krumelur: there are some tricky situations with inheritance and reflection. I had issues with NHibernate. It could be a nice feature, but you have to know what you are doing.

Comment: True. But then, I believe that applies for most things :)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by the other posters, you have implemented the interface explicitly.  The other option is to implement it like so:

```
string MyFunction()
{
   do something;
}
```

In my experience you only explicitly implement an interface when you are worried that the names of functions in multiple interfaces will collide, but they have different implementations.

Answer (score 0):

I often use a variation of the following pattern with explicit interfaces:

```
string IMyInterface.MyFunction()
{
    _myPrivateFunction();
}

string _myPrivateFunction()
{
    //Do Stuff...
}
```